# How to rewrite "node->left->key" replacing -> with "(*)." in C++?

Tags: c++14, nodes, b-tree

I'm new to the "->" symbol, so I'm instead replacing it with (*). . However, when I came across the line of code below, I tried replacing it and it didn't work. What am I doing wrong and is there any way to rewrite it?

I keep getting the error that "key" is a pointer and when I rewrite it, it doesn't work. I have triple checked my code, and yet I still don't understand.

```
 struct Node{
    int key;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
 };

  Node* createNode(int key){
   Node *node = new Node();
   (*node).key = key;
   (*node).left = NULL;
   (*node).right = NULL;
   return node;
  }


  int main(){
     Node *root = createNode(1);
     (*root).left = createNode(9);
     cout << root->left->key;  // Correct?
     cout << " OR ";
     cout << ((*root).left).(*key); 
    // this is where my code goes wrong and if I remove the (*) from key
    // and just leave it like .key it's wrong because key has to be a pointer
     return 0;
  }
```

I expect the output to be "9 OR 9" but it doesn't even let me compile past that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid the `->` operator, you can write it like this:

```
 cout << (*((*root).left)).key;
```

... but that's painful to write and painful to read, so it makes a great example of why the `->` operator is useful :)

Comment: Thanks so much! Though how does it make key a pointer? Sorry, I'm a noob.

Comment: `key` isn't a pointer, it's an `int`, as declared in your Node struct:  `int key;`

Comment: Oh. Ok, so `root` and `left` are both pointers, but why does my notation provide an error?

Comment: I see two errors in your line `cout << ((*root).left).(*key);` -- the first error is in the `(*key)` part -- you're trying to use the `*` operator to dereference an int (i.e. `key`), but it doesn't make sense to dereference an int, you can only dereference pointers.  The other error is that the expression `((*root).left)` is a pointer type (because `left` is declared as `Node *left;` in your struct), but you are have a `.` after it, and the `.` operator expects a `class` or `struct` object on its left-hand side, not a pointer.

Comment: Oh. Ok, thanks so much. I didn't know that about the `.` operator. Thank you!